# WP Use Profile Fields is missing

Tags: profiles

The entire User Profile Fields link is missing and I cant make new pages. We use Vibe BP and WPLMS systems and every time there is a critical error, WP cites the issue in line 69 in vibe bp code

Comment: Welcome to the WP Stack.  It sounds like you have a conflict.  Try a default theme and disable plugins to see if the issue persists.   From your note it looks like perhaps it's VIBE BP causing the issue so you'll want to check with them if that's the case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.